# Asking location permission in Android React Native module, Kotlin

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin

I am trying to code a library but I don't know much java or kotlin, so I ended up a code like this;

```
class DigitalVerificationModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

override fun getName(): String {
    return "DigitalVerification"
}

// Example method
// See https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android
@ReactMethod
fun multiply(a: Int, b: Int, promise: Promise) {
      promise.resolve(a * b)
    }
@ReactMethod
 fun locationManager() {
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)

}

}
```

The problem with this is when I call the locationManager in my react native example app, it says;

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is DigitalVerificationModule but Context was expected
```

I think this is a problem with `this` keyword. It points the DigitalVerificatinModule class but it should point something called `Context` I believe. But not sure how to handle this. All I want to achieve is making the permission popup appear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing `this` you should be able to just pass reactContext so now it becomes:

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(reactContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) }
```

you might also need to change your class constructor like this:

```
class DigitalVerificationModule(val reactContext: ReactApplicationContext)
```

Otherwise you can't use `reactContext`.